# Boostrap 3 - pull navigation to bottom

Tags: css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm trying to do something like this

[image]

using bootstrap3

But i have problem with that simple navigation. I need to place them at the bottom of column.

Check this code plz : http://www.bootply.com/LY3P6GAp1p

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1" style="display: table-cell;">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">Some text</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a hre="#">Option1</a></li>
                    <li><a hre="#">Option2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to use : position relative/absolute, table, table-cell - nothing works :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a hre="#">Option1</a></li>
                    <li><a hre="#">Option2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


<div class="col-md-6" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; position:absolute; right:0; bottom:20px">
```

Comment: Thank's for reply but, all codes with 'position : absolute' are not responsive :/

@spry_nandkishore : your solution : http://www.bootply.com/7jA7PIGsIO   - I just add borders - so it's wrong - but thank's anyway.

I wrote some code with 
  
> table / table-row and table-cell

http://www.bootply.com/Dm75PTp84q

but it's still not responsive.

Must be some way to do this without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0">
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please provide some commentary or a description of what this does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.content {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;

        }
```

HTML:

```
       <div class="row div1">
            <div id="Div1" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2>Some text</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="Div2" class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills content">
                    <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var divHeight = $("#Div1")[0].clientHeight;
            $("#Div2").css('height', divHeight + 'px');
        });
```

Hope this maybe useful